# How to create a document with tags using CMIS

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis

I would like to post a document with tags to an Alfresco. Is it possible to do it with CMIS ou should I use Alfresco public api ?
I know it was not possible in older versions, but in 2018 ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see existing tags when seeing a document in CMIS Workbench? Maybe tags are stored as properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use public REST api for creating your nodes and managing their tags.
In order to have a better idea on what that public API provides, check the api-explorer at 
https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/